# Attempting to disconnect in Roku channel throws error

Tags: roku, brightscript

I’m trying to get the [sample auth linking Roku channel](https://github.com/rokudev/sample-channels/blob/master/auth-linking-channel.zip) to work. I’ve installed the channel on my Roku stick, set up endpoints for generating and authenticating tokens, but can’t get the disconnect endpoint to work. The [Roku Developer Documentation on Authentication and Linking](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Authentication+and+Linking) is also useless, as the responses on that page don’t match what I’ve had to actually return from my application.

My code to disconnect looks like this:

```basic
sub parseDis(job as object)
  result = job.context.context.response
  json = parseJSON(result.content)
  if json.success = "no"
    m.top.disconnect = false
  else
    m.top.disconnect = true
  end if
end sub
```

So from my application, I’m returning a JSON response that looks like this:

```json
{
    "success": "yes"
}
```

But in the Telnet debug console session I get this output:

```
Suspending threads...
Thread selected:  2*   ...:/components/RegistryTask.xml(55)    
Current Function:
052:  sec.Write(key, val)
      Function RegWrite(key, val, section=invalid)
053:          if section = invalid then section = "Default"
054:          sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", section)
055:*         sec.Write(key, val)
056:          sec.Flush() 'commit it
057:        End Function
Type Mismatch. (runtime error &h18) in pkg:/components/RegistryTask.xml(55)
055:         sec.Write(key, val)
Backtrace:
#1  Function regwrite(key As Dynamic, val As Dynamic) As Dynamic
   file/line: pkg:/components/RegistryTask.xml(55)
#0  Function go() As Void
   file/line: pkg:/components/RegistryTask.xml(35)
Local Variables:
key              roString refcnt=3 val:"UNIQUE_ID_HERE3500X"
val              Invalid
section          String (VT_STR_CONST) val:"Default"
global           Interface:ifGlobal
m                roAssociativeArray refcnt=3 count:3
sec              bsc:roRegistrySection refcnt=1
Threads:
ID    Location                                Source Code
 0    pkg:/source/main.brs(15)                msg = wait(0, m.port)
 1    pkg:/components/SimpleScene.brs(78)     oauth_token: invalid
 2*   ...:/components/RegistryTask.xml(55)    sec.Write(key, val)
 3[u] ??
  *selected   [u]unattached(not debuggable)
```

Any one able to help my decipher as to what’s happening and going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate reason for the error is this:

```
key              roString refcnt=3 val:"UNIQUE_ID_HERE3500X"
val              Invalid
```

`Write()` function takes 2 strings, key and value - and the value in this case is `invalid`, no good.

I had a quick look at the sample app and the deeper reason behind is that `onDisconnect()` event handler does:

```
m.regTask.write = {
  deviceID: m.rokuDeviceID,
  oauth_token: invalid
}
```

That has to be fixed one way or another. I did not look in more details - e.g. if empty string will do to the logic or better use `roRegistrySection.delete()`